# Incomplete FBO when attaching RBO

Tags: c++, opengl, fbo, depth-buffer

I'm trying to attach a RenderBuffer Object to a FrameBuffer object, and `glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` keeps returning me the error code : `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`

(I'm trying attach a DepthBuffer)

Here is my code (simplified):

```cpp
// Create and bind the new FBO (1920x1080)

GLuint gBuffer; 
glGenFramebuffers(1, &gBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer);


// Create, initialize, bind and attach the new RBO (purpose : depth buffering)

GLuint rbo;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);


// Create, bind, and initialize, and attach a texture (the FBO's Color Buffer)

GLuint idMap;
glGenTextures(1, &idMap);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, idMap);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, idMap, 0);

std::cout << std::to_string(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)) << std::endl; // Gives me 36054 ( incomplete ???)


// Re-binding orignal FBO and RBO

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

---

Things I noticed

I accidentally wrote

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
```

Instead of

```
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);
```

...And there was no error, but the depth test wasn't working at all.

**EDIT : It is simply because `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` is necessary to attach the buffer. It was just out of the framebuffer...**

When rendering in the FBO, I do :

```cpp
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer); // Use secondary FBO
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, rbo);   // Use secondary DepthBuffer
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);                       // Allow depth writing
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                    // Enable Depth testing
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);                       // Pass if fragment is nearer
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear color and depth buffers

Render(); 

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);       // Go back to original FBO  
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);     // to original Depth Buffer
```

Comment: You should try to rephrase your post into a question. Currently, your post is a series of statements.

Comment: @JoakimThorén Ok ! editing

Comment: @JoakimThorén Is it better ?

Comment: The fact that mistakenly specifying `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` instead of `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` when attaching `rbo` resulted in the FBO being considered complete suggests, perhaps, that `rbo` does not pass the [attachment complete](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Attachment_Completeness) requirements.  Maybe?

Comment: @G.M. I don't know what you mean the 2nd parameter of  [`glRenderbufferStorage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glRenderbufferStorage.xhtml) has to be the internal format (e.g. `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16 `) and the 3rd parameter of  [`glFramebufferRenderbuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glFramebufferRenderbuffer.xhtml) has to be `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` for the depth buffer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 The code I'm referring to was removed by the 1st edit unfortunately.  The OP reported that the FBO was considered complete when they mistakenly invoked `glFramebufferRenderbuffer` with a 2nd parameter of `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` rather than `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`.

Comment: @G.M. Ah, I see. Of course the framebuffer is complete in this case, because the depth buffer is not attached at all (`GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` is not a valid attachment point). A framebuffer with a color buffer only is complete.

Comment: @Rabbid76 @G.M. I'm back, thanks for you replies. Ok so ```GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16``` instead of  ```GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT``` just doesn't attach the buffer, I see.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried both ```GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24``` and ```GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8``` and the same problem occurs...

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes .

Comment: @Rabbid76 I changed several lines and it works now, figuring out why.

Comment: @Kiord I think its better now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed step by step this tutorial : http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/fr/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-14-render-to-texture/

The errror occurs when this block of code is missing :

```cpp
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

It's the parameters of the texture (color buffer).
In particular, only the second line is necessary to avoid the `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` error.

It seems that adding a depth buffer without setting some of the texture filtering parameters won't work. (However, it works when there is only a color buffer, surprinsing)

Comment: Oh yes, because by default the value of `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`

Comment: Ok, It makes sense now.